# Pandas DataFrame group by value and get column & row indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like following.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5),columns=['1','2','3','4','5'])

         1         2         3         4         5
0  0.877455 -1.215212 -0.453038 -1.825135  0.440646
1  1.640132 -0.031353  1.159319 -0.615796  0.763137
2  0.132355 -0.762932 -0.909496 -1.012265 -0.695623
3 -0.257547 -0.844019  0.143689 -2.079521  0.796985
4  2.536062 -0.730392  1.830385  0.694539 -0.654924
```

I need to get row and column indexes for following three groups. (In my original dataset there are no negative values)

1. value is greater than 2.0
2. value is between 1.0 - 2.0
3. value is less than 1.0

For e.g for "value is greater than 2.0" it should return [1,4]. I have tried using this which gives a boolean result.

```
df.values > 2
```

Comment: That returns a numpy array, you could just use the mask to perform the dataframe selection like `df[df > 2]` this returns a dataframe with `NaN` for values that do not satisfy the boolean criteria and the values that do as a dataframe. Up to you what you then do with `NaN` values, either set to `0` or drop them using `dropna`

Comment: @EdChum : Ok, so how to get row and column index pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where` on the boolean result to extract the indices:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5),columns=['1','2','3','4','5'])
condition = df.values > 2
print np.column_stack(np.where(condition))
```

For a `df` like this,

```
          1         2         3         4         5
0  0.057347  0.722251  0.263292 -0.168865 -0.111831
1 -0.765375  1.040659  0.272883 -0.834273 -0.126997
2 -0.023589  0.046002  1.206445  0.381532 -1.219399
3  2.290187  2.362249 -0.748805 -1.217048 -0.973749
4  0.100084  0.671120 -0.211070  0.903264 -0.312815
```

Output:

```
[[3 0]
 [3 1]]
```

Or get a list of row-column index pairs if necessary:

```
print map(list, np.column_stack(np.where(condition)))
```

Output:

```
[[3,0], [3,1]]
```